# Why doesn't my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive get called when the BroadcastReceiver is an inner class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, inner-classes

When I have the AlarmReceiver class below in it's own file, the log statement gets logged and the onReceive method gets called. I need to make my BroadcastReceiver an inner class so I can call getFragmentManager() from my Activity. However, when I make it an inner class to my main Activity class, it does not get called. Why is that?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { //this needs to be an inner class to access the activity

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                Log.d("BROADCAST","RECEIVED");
                //start a new activity, an alarm has gone off
                AlarmFragment alarmFragment=new AlarmFragment();  
              // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, alarmFragment).commit();

            }
        }

public void setAlarm(){
   Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

   //Get the Alarm Service
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   Long currentTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();

   //DEBUG TIME
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,currentTime+7500,PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

> Why is that?

you are got major fundamental mistake about how to send and receive broadcast mechanism works:

you are providing to alarm manager a `PendingIntent` to start broadcast, but in practice - you providing it intent without any Action specified.

**sending broadcast without an action is meaningless!!!**

you should add to the `intentAlarm` object an custom action string that identify your broadcast, and register your `AlarmReceiver` receiver programatically with an IntentFilter that handles this custom action:

```
 Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(CUSTOM_ACTION_STRING);
 ....
 ....
```

(you should hold reference to an instance of your AlarmReceiver class.  that's the mAlarmReceiver ...)
add to the Activity `onResume()` callback registration to the broadcast:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(mAlarmReceiver , new IntentFilter(CUSTOM_ACTION_STRING));
}
```

don't forget also to unregister the receiver:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mAlaramReceiver);

    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: While that is all interesting, and I may try it, I would still like to know why this works when I move the class into another file and does not work when it is an inner class.

Comment: @TylerPfaff: it's not suppose to work even if it's not nested class.   if it's working - then it's bug in the OS or in your device firmware. broadcastReceiver suppose to wake up and perform the onReceive method when a broadcast with appropriate intent filter that it currently registered to is sent

Comment: @TylerPfaff: by the way - if the alarm you are setting is only for perform fragment transaction after some time - then using AlarmManager that sending broadcast is a completly overhead. there are much simpler ways to do that,  such posting delayed runnable via handler.

Comment: perhaps it works because you can declare a receiver in the manifest?  <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"/>

Comment: I'll look into the delayed runnable via handler, thanks.

Comment: Even if the receiver is declerad in the manifest - it should have intent filter tag with one or more actions

Comment: Note: An explicit intent is always delivered to its target, regardless of any intent filters the component declares.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly change your Activity Class to FragmentActivity and also Access with context Object,like below code.

```
arg0.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, alarmFragment).commit();
```

Its is a Try. Kindly let me know your feedback.

Comment: The context object is not an Activity context.

Comment: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity